# With Gekko, is it possible to create sub-model or merge models together?

Tags: python, gekko

An example would be 2 models (m1 & m2) that work and can be tested independently. One model have an exogenous variable, let say m2 and varX. For now varX = anyConstant

Then without having to copy paste all the code, I want the output of m1 to be the input for varX (which become endogenous) in m2. I now would have a unique model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two models and export values from the first model to be used in the second model. Here is an example that creates two models `m1` and `m2`. The first model is solved to determine the value of `x1` that is exported by assigning `output_m1` to `x1.value[0]`. This is an input parameter of the second model with `varX = m2.Param(value=output_m1)`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

# Model 1 (m1)
m1 = GEKKO(remote=False)
x1 = m1.Var(value=1, lb=0)
m1.Equation(x1**2 == 4)
m1.solve(disp=False)
output_m1 = x1.value[0]
print(f"Output from m1: {output_m1}")

# Model 2 (m2)
m2 = GEKKO(remote=False)
varX = m2.Param(value=output_m1)
x2 = m2.Var(value=1)
m2.Equation(2*x2 - varX == 0)
m2.solve(disp=False)
print(f"Output from m2: {x2.value[0]}")
```

The output from this code is:

```
Output from m1: 2.0000000929
Output from m2: 1.0
```

The value of `varX` can also be updated if there are multiple solutions such as with `varX.value=output_m1`.